# Discriminated unions with boolean

Tags: typescript

**Problem**:

Discrimination union with boolean type seems to work only for true associated type.

**Reproducer**:

```
interface DummyA {
  hint: true
  a: string
}

interface DummyB {
  hint: false
  b: string
}

type Dummy =
  | DummyA
  | DummyB;

const dummies: Dummy[] = [
  {
    hint: true,
    a: "a"
  },
  {
    hint: false,
    b: "b"
  }
]

dummies.forEach(value => {
  if (value.hint) {
    value.a
  } else {
    value.b
  }
})
```

**Expected result**:

If it works with true, it should work with false. Is this the normal behavior, or more like an issue ?

Comment: It works as expected for me. What's the problem you have?

Comment: This works with strict null checks

Comment: Well, in fact with value.hint === true, it works. As @TitianCernicova-Dragomir said, it related to non strict null checks ! Thanks.

I guess without those checks, if condition type must be null | boolean and then if cannot inf for else as it could be null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `strictNullChecks` this will work as expected. If you don't use strict null checks (as I suspect based on your question) you can get this to work if you use `=== true`

```
dummies.forEach(value => {
  if (value.hint === true) {
    value.a
  } else {
    value.b
  }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=32&ssc=3&pln=25&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIFcC2mCeBBZAbwChlkALUMALmTCnQlOTloGd7QBzYgX2OJVo8JGiy4AQkWaVwteABs2TMgCN2nED37EwOAA4oM2HMgC8zAD5iTeKzckBuAQgD2IDsgAm44BDa0xrgA2gC65sjBzCRkZLI0dAwQADTMZKzIAERwmcy8qWQxsfHycEopacjqWaq5ZPyhAj7YfmwAdDCuUACiiOQAFABuZYzmAHzSZMAwyEMjEG3x5mZmiYwAlJOxwwqMbXB5yBDlW2Q7e6p5fOtAA)

Comment: why is `=== true` required if strictNullChecks is not needed?  If the compiler is worried that `hint` may not be defined, shouldn't checking `value.hint` be sufficient?